# Overlapping instances ok, but still fails

Tags: haskell, typeclass

When I enter the following in Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

class Class a

instance Class a
instance Eq a => Class a
```

I get this error when I load it up into GHCi:

```
Test.hs:5:10:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance [overlap ok] Class a -- Defined at Test.hs:5:10
      instance [overlap ok] Eq a => Class a -- Defined at Test.hs:6:10
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I sort of understand why it is failing, seeing that both are instances for `a` and neither is more specific, assuming that constraints are ignored. But why is it saying that overlap is ok?

Also, is it possible to add a language extension to allow these kinds of overlap to work and would that be useful?

And finally, is what I intend possible in the current GHC in another way (what I intend is to use one piece of code for instances of `Eq` and another for the rest)?

Comment: [this haskellwiki article](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/AdvancedOverlap#Choosing_a_type-class_instance_based_on_the_context) gives some ways to handle it, but for those options you basically have to list types that are in `Eq`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "But why is it saying that overlap is ok?"

Because you told it so with the language pragma.

Note that these instances are not merely overlapping, they are *identical*, as far as GHC's instance resolution is concerned. GHC knows no way at all to ever distinguish these instances, hence it rejects them. Not even `IncoherentInstances` helps with GHC yet. It will help in GHC 7.8, as [Joachim Breitner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/946226/joachim-breitner) [just notified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615649/overlapping-instances-ok-but-still-fails/18615978?noredirect=1#comment27403450_18615978) me.

> And finally, is what I intend possible in the current GHC in another way (what I intend is to use one piece of code for instances of `Eq` and another for the rest)?

I would not be surprised if the new costraint kinds extensions would make it possible, but I've never worked with them, so I don't know how they work and what they can do. But your code would not look nearly as simple, if it works at all.

Comment: `IncoherentInstances` will help in 7.8: http://git.haskell.org/?p=ghc.git;a=commitdiff;h=099f9542e8ad2e38196de2be928ccbfaee545b44